# Replace HTTP_HOST from current URL in php

Tags: php

Suppose my current url is:

> www.example.com?id=10

```
if($_GET['id']==10):
    //replace current $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; with www.example1.com without removing other parts of url and redirect.
else :
    //replace current $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; with www.example2.com without removing other parts of url and redirect.
endif:
```

I need to replace current `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`.

How to do this using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect then here is the code-

```
$request =  $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];   
if($_GET['id']==10):
   $url = "www.example1.com/".$request;
else :
   $url = "www.example1.com/".$request;
endif;
```

else I would like to know for what purpose you want to change current url.